# Autocomplete ui not working on internet explorer 8

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

i'm using Autocomplete ui jquery on firefox and chrome it's work ok, but in ie8 the button is Missing
you can see it on jquery example (open the link on ie8):

[the button is missing](http://matisapps.com/autoComplete.png) 

[autoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

i think that if i change Something on the css it will work but i didnt success.
Is there a solution for it?

Comment: It works for me in IE8

Comment: i have also used autocomplete. For me it works fine on every browser even in IE 7 used this way [link](http://www.johnstonianera.com/jquery-autocomplete-xml/)

Comment: the button is missing, look on the link to the image.

Comment: for that u should use IE9 and above

Comment: are you sure that there is no solution to ie8?

Comment: It suppose to work on IE7+. In my virtualBox IE enters to compatibility mode when I open jqui site! o_O
Open a bug in their repository - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/search?q=Autocomplete+combobox+ie8&noquickjump=1&ticket=on&changeset=on&milestone=on&wiki=on